# Неверный вывод массива

Tags: java

Почему при выводе всех индексов кроме последнего, вместо введенного числа выводит 0?
И как это исправить?

Можете использовать пример:

```
2 7 8
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0; 
        n = scan.nextInt(); 
        int nums[] = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            nums = new int[n];
            nums[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я еще добавил пару новых замечаний и обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в данной строке

```
nums = new int[n];
```

В цикле после ввода каждой последующей цифры Вы просто создаёте заново новый массив.
Соответственно каждую новую итерацию Вы стираете ранее введенные значения.
И в массиве `nums` храниться только последнее введенное число.
Нули выводятся, же потому что ими инициализируется массив `int[]` при его создании.

Просто удалите или закомментируйте эту строку.

**Замечания:**

```
int nums[] = new int[100];
```

Вы строкой выше Вы ввели размер массива и позже создаёте массив с размером 100.

- Во-первых: при вводе последовательности размером больше 100 у Вас возникнет ошибка
- Во-вторых: при вводе массива меньше 100 Вы будете израсходовать лишнюю память.
- В-третьих: вы не сможете нормально оперировать с массивом в дальнейшем, потому что его фактический размер отличается от реально используемых массивом значений

Лучше сразу инициализировать массив с реальным размером:

```
    int nums[] = new int[n];
```

Далее Вы сможете итерировать массив следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
   //...
}
```

Таким образом Вы сможете корректно работать с массивом не зная значения переменной `n`. 
Это Вам может понадобится, когда вы передаете данный массив в качестве параметра в другой метод.

А когда при итерации Вам нужны только значения(без индексов) можно поступить еще проще:

```
for (int number : nums){
    // ...
}
```

Так можно поступить во втором случае при выводе массива:

```
for (int number : nums){
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Итого:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Введите размер массива:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите размер значения:");
        int nums[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            // nums = new int[n];
            nums[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Вы ввели следующие значения:");
        for (int number : nums){
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то я голову ломал, что не так.